# How do you reinstall Ubuntu after deleting python3.6?

Tags: command-line, uninstall, python3, text

I recently made the stupid mistake of uninstalling python3.6 because I upgraded to python 3.9, not knowing how important python is for Ubuntu.

I got signed out automatically and when I tried to sign in it said something like "Start of session failed" (it could have been something slightly different, I don't remember exactly), so I rebooted my computer and then, instead of showing my username, a text console was shown.

I asked about it in another question and they told me that the easiest solution is to back up my files and completely reinstall everything.

However, I don't know how to get out of the text console, Ctrl+Alt+F7 doesn't work and neither does "Login as root"

Also, I don't know how to recover my files, I plugged in a flash drive and nothing happened.

Comment: Changing or deleting the standard python version of Ubuntu is a unrecouverable error. You need to reinstall.

Boot from a live DVD or USB and reinstall. If your live DVD/USB is the same version as the installed Ubuntu version, you will see a "Reinstall" option. This will reinstall the system in the same setup as the existing installation, without formatting the partitions. That way, your user data and user configuration will be preserved.

Comment: @David But how do I boot from the text console, that's all I can access?

Comment: @karel, yes this answers my question but it wouldn't have worked. My problem is fixed now but before my user had been deleted, so I couldn't enter my username and password from the text console. Still, for somebody else it can be useful so I'll mark it as helpful to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Changing or deleting the standard python version of Ubuntu is a unrecoverable error.

You need to reinstall.

Boot from a live DVD or USB and reinstall.

If your live DVD/USB is the same version as the installed Ubuntu version, you will see a "Reinstall" option.

This will reinstall the system in the same setup as the existing installation, without formatting the partitions. That way, your user data and user configuration will be preserved

Comment: But how do I boot from the text console if that's all I have access to?

Comment: type: `sudo shutdown -r now`

Comment: You boot from the live media you are re installing.

Comment: Thank you David, that worked perfectly

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to accept. It is accepted now